# Is there a way to recover the undertale genocide route after fighting mettaton NEO

Tags: undertale

I was doing an undertale genocide route and I read a post that said an undertale genocide route would be cancelled if you fight Mettaton NEO before clearing Hotland/The Core. Is there a way to recover the genocide route without reseting?

I fought Mettaton NEO before clearing Hotland/The Core and I can't encounter an monster.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the only way I know to return to genocide route after defeating mettaton NEO early, is to quit without saving. It’s easy to accidentally ruin a genocide run.